# Getting an error when attempting to install Homebrew on CentOS 7: “Error: Unknown command: shellenv”

Tags: linux, installation, shell, centos, homebrew

I am trying to install brew on CentOS 7 and get the following error:

```
[jalal@goku ~]$ git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
Cloning into '/home/grad3/jalal/.linuxbrew/Homebrew'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 418, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (418/418), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (231/231), done.
remote: Total 178024 (delta 237), reused 341 (delta 176), pack-reused 177606
Receiving objects: 100% (178024/178024), 46.71 MiB | 22.72 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (132086/132086), done.
Checking out files: 100% (2559/2559), done.
[jalal@goku ~]$ mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/grad3/jalal/.linuxbrew/bin’: File exists
[jalal@goku ~]$ ln -s ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/grad3/jalal/.linuxbrew/bin/brew’: File exists
[jalal@goku ~]$ eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
Error: Unknown command: shellenv
```

Is there an alternate way of installing brew in CentOS 7 or how can I fix this issue?

I followed the instructions here https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
Release:    7.9.2009
Codename:   Core
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t know Homebrew worked on Linux. But apparently it does!

Seems like [those are the official instructions](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux) you reference indicate that you need to install some prerequisites before the steps you got to. Just run these two commands and you should be good:

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
sudo yum install curl file git
```

Then afterwards run these commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin
ln -s ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin
eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

That said, if you have followed those instructions and still have issues I would recommend deleting  `~/.linuxbrew/bin` like this:

```
rm -rf  ~/.linuxbrew/
```

Then go through the steps to install it again. The reason I recommend that is looking at the chain of error messages at the end of your command output:

```
[jalal@goku ~]$ mkdir ~/.linuxbrew/bin
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/grad3/jalal/.linuxbrew/bin’: File exists
[jalal@goku ~]$ ln -s ~/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/bin/brew ~/.linuxbrew/bin
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/home/grad3/jalal/.linuxbrew/bin/brew’: File exists
[jalal@goku ~]$ eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
Error: Unknown command: shellenv
```

My guess is you have a failed install located in `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/grad3/jalal/.linuxbrew/bin’: File exists` and because of that, the commands can’t be run properly. Just ditch `~/.linuxbrew/` and reinstall and it should work.

Remember, installing stuff like this for your user — under `~/.linuxbrew/` — is easy to remove and reinstall so that is always a safe option.

Comment: yes I already have seen those and had installed the prereqs. Ran them again and here's what you see https://pastebin.com/raw/NxbDmkhY

Comment: @MonaJalal Edited my answer, but I would then recommend deleting the existing install like this and reinstalling: `rm -rf  ~/.linuxbrew/`. There is something weird in that directory right now on your system so just blow it away and start again; not a heavy lift for an install like this. Read the edited answer for more details.