# Changing the installation path of brew script in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, installation, centos, environment-variables, homebrew

I am trying to install brew using the following script:

```
$ sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Linuxbrew has been merged into Homebrew.
Please migrate to the following command:
  /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"

==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
==> This script will install:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/doc/homebrew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew
==> The following new directories will be created:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/include
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/var
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/zsh
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/zsh/site-functions
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/var/homebrew
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/var/homebrew/linked
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Caskroom
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Frameworks

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/linuxbrew’: Permission denied
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew
```

In my current machine, I do not have access to `/home` directory but I have access to `/home/grad3/jalal` so how I can change the directory from `/home` to `/home/grad3/jalal` or `/scratch3` for which I have access?

Comment: Sorry you are running into this issue, but you already posted another question that is quite similar: [Getting an error when attempting to install Homebrew on CentOS 7: “Error: Unknown command: shellenv”](https://superuser.com/questions/1638315/getting-an-error-when-attempting-to-install-homebrew-on-centos-7-error-unknow)

Comment: well that's another way of installing it. I think this question is fair and shouldn't be closed. they are two different errors using two different commands.